# False compile error during mvn release:perform says invalid pom while pom is fine and code compiles

Tags: maven-release-plugin

While trying to release new version of **our-test-tools** project I get:

1. Warning on invalid POM

> [WARNING] The POM for org.synyx.hades:org.synyx.hades:jar:1.6.3.RELEASE-2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

2. Compilation error

> COMPILATION ERROR: [...] package org.springframework.jdbc.datasource
>   does not exist

#### However!

There's **no compile error** in **our-test-tools** and **synyx's POM is valid**.

1. Following works (Maven reports success):

   - `mvn install` also with `-o` on project I'm trying to release
   - `mvn release:prepare`
   - `mvn install` on checked out project (check out done by `mvn release:perform` itself)
   - `mvn verify` or `mvn help:effective-pom` on synyx project
2. Following did not help:

   - cleaning local repository
   - updating dependent project to make preferred Maven profile active
   - -e and -X switches - I found no clues

Any ideas what can be wrong or what can I try?

#### Further info:

1. SCM = Git.
2. **our-test-tools* project POM: http://pastebin.com/vkaXshhL

Comment: Where do you get `org.synyx.hades 1.6.3.RELEASE-2` from? It's not in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.synyx.hades%22%20AND%20a%3A%22org.synyx.hades%22), so we can't check it's really valid. There is only version `1.6.3.RELEASE` (without the `-2`).

Comment: Apology for tardiness in coming back to this. We've made a manual release and this stopped being relevant. I'll try replicating again soon.

Version -2 is a version with our changes done there, but even with 1.6.3.RELEASE, without the -2 problem persist. Actually, we believed that it's lack of -2 version was the problem but turned out that was false lead.